# Docker: Mailhog "connection refused"

Tags: docker, mailhog

I have a `php-fpm` container which should be sending mail to another container using Mailhog.  The error message is:

```
 Swift_TransportException: Connection could not be established with host mailhog [Connection refused #111]
```

The container definition looks like this:

```
 mailhog:
   image: mailhog/mailhog:latest
   restart: unless-stopped
   ports: 
     - 1025:1025
     - 8025:8025
   networks:
     mine:
       aliases:
         -mailhog
```

The command to send mail is:

```
 /usr/bin/mhsendmail --smtp-addr mailhog:1025
```

... which superficially seems to me to be everything that *(the Mailhog docs say ...)* I should need to make this work.  So, what exactly can cause `connection refused`?

---

Okay, I can see from other sources that this message means, "no process is listening or it's blocked by a firewall."

Comment: Are the containers on the same network ?  Try to ping mailhog from your php container.

Answer (score 0):

*False Alarm!*

I determined that the `php.ini` settings for mail were incorrect.  They specified the wrong port!